# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get the geolocation of my user that works fine, but when I try to put a spinner directive I get the following error.

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'icon-end: false'. Current value: 'icon-end: true'.
```

The spinner is from this package https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/spinner/overview#nbspinnerdirective . This directive works fine with observables when I put this.cdr.detectChanges() in the subscribe also note that my detection strategy is changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

I try with setTimeout approach too and not work, zone.run ony and detectChange only too . Any ideas ?

Template button

```
<ng-template #whereT>
<button nbButton outline (click)="getMyLocation()" [nbSpinner]="loadingGetPosition">
                      <nb-icon icon="navigation-2-outline" pack="eva"></nb-icon>
                    </button>
<ng-template>
```

Component Ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurant-list-virtual',
  templateUrl: './restaurant-list-virtual.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurant-list-virtual.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RestaurantListVirtualComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
   ...

constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private geocodeService: GeocodeService,
    private toastrService: NbToastrService,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {
  }
getMyLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      this.loadingGetPosition = true;
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.loadingGetPosition = false;
          this.locationSelected({ latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude });
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });

      },
        (error) => {
          this.toastrService.warning(
            this.translate.instant('restaurants.filter.button.getLocalization'),
            this.translate.instant('restaurants.filter.button.warningLocalization'),
            {
              duration: 8000
            });
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1**

I figure out that the problem only occurs when the button is inner  outside of this works correctly any workaround or idea about what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the error I figure out that the problem happen with the version 4.6.0 (with 4.1.0 works fine).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mh5jx3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

Comment: If you wrap  this.loadingGetPosition = true; inside setTimeout. is it throwing same error?

Comment: yep if I wrap both loadingGetPosition or one only and still get the error.